# Why is the language not updating after closing and reopening the app?

Tags: java, android

I'm create a simple project in android studio to practice on language changing. I do it through "choose language" button butt in running mood it's work fine, while I used shared preferences to keep change the after closing and reopen the app, but when I reopen the app default language(English) again set on the app although I change the language before closing the app. Here is my code. Please help me where I am doing wrong!

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityLoginBinding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_login);
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        loadLocale();
        binding.btnChangeLanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeLanguage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeLanguage() {
        final String languages [] = {"عربي", "বাংলা", "English", "हिंदी", "اردو"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_language);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(languages, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which==0) {
                    setLocale("ar");
                    recreate();
                }
                else if (which==1) {
                    setLocale("bn");
                    recreate();
                }
                else if (which==2) {
                    setLocale("");
                    recreate();
                }
                else if (which==3) {
                    setLocale("hi");
                    recreate();
                }
                else if (which==4) {
                    setLocale("ur");
                    recreate();
                }

            }
        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }

    private void setLocale(String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("appLanguage", language);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Language Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private void loadLocale() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = preferences.getString("appLanguage", "");
        setLocale(language);
    }
}
```